# Read excel file from clientside using symfony2 netbeans

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, symfony, javascript

Please help any one...

I am trying to read excel file from client side and insert to mysql with out uploading excel file to server

can any one help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is not really related to asp, symfony or php. you have to find a pure client solution with JavaScript or similar to parse the excel file.

Please check [Stackoverflow Question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630413/how-can-i-read-an-excel-file-with-javascript-without-activexobject)

If you are able to extract it to pure text like csv you can transmit it in a form to the server and load it to you DB.