# how to upload a excel sheet using javascript and to validate the contents present in it e.g.timesheet validation

Tags: javascript

i need to create a webpage which will take excel sheet as an input and it should process the data in the excel sheet as mentioned below.

it should be done in an weekly basis,
it should calculate 6 hours per day which is entered in various rows,
Is it possible to validate the data present in an excel sheet for a particular date in various rows but in the same column for an amount of 20 persons.
It should send a mail to the boss with the names of those who are not properly filled their data by adding them in cc..

If it is possible to do kindly tell me how to do..
Thanks in ADVANCE..

Comment: Hi, Please let us know your approach, what have you tried and the problem you face in your code. You will hardly find a readymade answer here. Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read an Excel File with JavaScript (without ActiveXObject)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630413/how-can-i-read-an-excel-file-with-javascript-without-activexobject)

Answer (score 0):

To validate the excel in javascript

[validate excel using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630413/how-can-i-read-an-excel-file-with-javascript-without-activexobject)

and, you can use uploadify or async file uploader to upload the excel sheet