# How to validate for a corrupt csv/excel file react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, react-redux, frontend

I have a situation where the user uploads an excel or csv file but before user can submit form I need to check if the file is valid and not corrupt. Corrupt file can be a file which was created by just changing the extension of zip to csv/xlsx or exe to csv/xlsx.

As a solution i'm reading the file and checking first 100 characters for any Unicodes if there are any i consider that file to be corrupt.

```
const validateFile = (fileObj) => {

  fileReader.onload = function (event) {
  const text = event.target.result;

  try {
    const text = event.target.result;

    if (
      REGEX_UNI.UNICODE_TEST.test(text.substring(0, 100))) {
         console.log('ERROR')
          return false;
    }
     return true;

  catch (e) {
    console.info('error');
    return false;
      }
    };

fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileObj);
   };
```

but the problem now comes in case for files with large data (1 million lines), in that case my browser freezes as reading 1million file is a complex task.

Is there any other way for me to do this ? Are there any libraries or packages that could help me achieve this.

Comment: Xlsx files **are zip files**

Comment: @James zip was just an example, it could be .exe to csv as well or any other format.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630413/how-can-i-read-an-excel-file-with-javascript-without-activexobject